# How to copy a list from a cell to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have this function which copy a sheet to another workbook.

```
Public Function copierFeuilleDeA(fromWb As Workbook, fromFeuille As String, toWb As Workbook, toFeuille As String) As Boolean

    copierFeuilleDeA = True

    On Error GoTo errorHandler

    fromWb.Worksheets(fromFeuille).Cells.Copy

    toWb.Worksheets(toFeuille).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
    toWb.Worksheets(toFeuille).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    toWb.Worksheets(toFeuille).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    toWb.Worksheets(toFeuille).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    toWb.Worksheets(toFeuille).Activate
    toWb.Worksheets(toFeuille).Range("A1").Select

    Exit Function

errorHandler:
    copierFeuilleDeA = False
    MsgBox Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description
End Function
```

The function works nice, it copies the values, the formats, the columns widths and the formulas, but doesn't copy the list which  is in the cell F26 (the items of the list are 0, 1, 2,3,4, 5).

So how to make this function copy the list?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to paste the data validation list as well.

```
toWb.Worksheets(toFeuille).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValidation
```